# Light & customizable React chart for PWA

Tags: reactjs, charts, progressive-web-apps, trading

I need a chart library for react.js to use in PWA Mobile,
therefore library need specifications:

- light , small and fast first load
- display financial data (candle, bar, line) chart
- Integrate and connect any data quick as possible
- flexible in changing style
- responsive and mobile-friendly
- free and open source
- ability to update chart in real time (like socket)

Comment: Try this https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/ i'm currently using and compared to recharts is easier to customize.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the LightWaight chart so beneficial for the project requirement. I highly recommend it for finance js developers.

[lightweight-charts](https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts)